# How to change text size from pixels to vw in this code?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any easy way to change text size from pixels to vw in this code?

Tried in css - no results.

```
const elem = document.querySelector("div");
const textEl = elem.querySelector("p");
const createBlotterText = () => {
const text = new Blotter.Text(textEl.innerHTML, {
family: "sans-serif",
weight: 700,
size: 100,
paddingLeft: 100,
paddingRight: 100,
paddingTop: 100,
paddingBottom: 100,
fill: "white"
  });
```

[**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/dackjaniels/pen/MWgvrrE)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for size, size code mentioned inside * mark. This code help you to convert px to vw.

```
const createBlotterText = () => {
const text = new Blotter.Text(textEl.innerHTML, {
  family: "sans-serif",
  weight: 700,
  *size: 100vw/500px,*
  paddingLeft: 100,
  paddingRight: 100,
  paddingTop: 100,
  paddingBottom: 100,
  fill: "white"
});
```

Comment: That's works for the size, but script isn't working now :/